# XML problem with carriage return

Tags: xml, flash, return

HI ,

I am developing an admin panel for an flash site. One of the sections contains large amount of text containing Carriage Returns. It can look as this :

```
  John Doe was born in Athens in 1974.
  He studied at the Athens School of Fine Arts and he presented his first solo exhibition in 1996.
```

So from the text area the text goes to mysql and from mysql I generate an XML file.
The problem is the xml file source is looking like this :

```
   John Doe was born in Athens in 1974. &#13;
   He studied at the Athens School of Fine Arts and he presented his first solo exhibition in 1996. &#13;
```

This way in flash the text has some big spaces between phrases and I dont like it.

Can you please tell me how to generate XML file to be like this :

```
  John Doe was born in Athens in 1974.
  He studied at the Athens School of Fine Arts and he presented his first solo exhibition in 1996.
```

Thank you

Comment: i forgot to mention I develop this project in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line terminator is there -- that's the `&#13;` (a carriage return (CR), 0x0D). Linefeeds (LF) are 0x0A and will be represented as `&#10;`.

write an XSLT or use some other means to transform the XML entity `&#13;` to a line break that Flash will recognize. You might want to think about which line terminators you'll accept as line termination conventions between operating systems:

- *nix (and OS X) like a straightforward carriage return (CR: 0x0D). That will show in in XML as `&#13;`
- Windows/DOS like to be complicated. a carriage return/linefeed pair (CR+LF: 0x0D0A) is preferred. That will show up in XML as `&#13;&#10;`.
- old-school Mac OS liked a single CR (0x0A) which will show up in XML as `&#10;`.

Note that for Unix and Windows, a standalone carriage return (CR) usually is interpreted to mean "*return to start of line*". The semantics of that is open to interpretation.

Comment: OMG ... In what I put myself into ...   This is my first thought when I read your answer Nicholas ... Can you please bare with me and give me a little more informations on "write an XSLT or use some other means to transform the XML entity &#13; "  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself the problem i think :

```
$input=preg_replace( '/\r/', ' ', trim($dd) );
```

the text would have from mysql \r\n and I needed only \n so ... I just removed the \r

Thanks